# Is there a numpy function that allows you to specify start, step, and number?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

We're all familiar with `np.linspace`, which creates an array given a `start`, `stop`, and `num` of elements:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.linspace(0, 10, 9)
Out[2]: array([  0.  ,   1.25,   2.5 ,   3.75,   5.  ,   6.25,   7.5 ,   8.75,  10.  ])
```

Likewise, who could ever forget `np.arange`, which creates an array given a `start`, `stop`, and `step`:

```
In [4]: np.arange(0, 10, 1.25)
Out[4]: array([ 0.  ,  1.25,  2.5 ,  3.75,  5.  ,  6.25,  7.5 ,  8.75])
```

But is there a function that allows you to specify a `start`, `step`, and `num` of elements, while omitting the `stop`?  There should be.

Comment: just write a small function that converts it over to np.arange where stop = step*num+start

or just pass that in the call

Comment: What about `numpy.arange(num) * step + start`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A deleted answer pointed out that `linspace` takes an `endpoint` parameter.

With that, 2 examples given in other answers can be written as:

```
In [955]: np.linspace(0, 0+(0.1*3),3,endpoint=False)
Out[955]: array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2])

In [956]: np.linspace(0, 0+(5*3),3,endpoint=False)
Out[956]: array([  0.,   5.,  10.])

In [957]: np.linspace(0, 0+(1.25*9),9,endpoint=False)
Out[957]: array([  0.  ,   1.25,   2.5 ,   3.75,   5.  ,   6.25,   7.5 ,   8.75,  10.  ])
```

Look at the functions defined in `numpy.lib.index_tricks` for other ideas on how to generate ranges and/or grids.  For example, `np.ogrid[0:10:9j]` behaves like `linspace`.

```
def altspace(start, step, count, endpoint=False, **kwargs):
   stop = start+(step*count)
   return np.linspace(start, stop, count, endpoint=endpoint, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 57):

The shortest and most elegant way (from my perspective) is:

```
import numpy as np

start = 0
step = 1.25
num = 9

result = start + np.arange(0, num) * step
```

returns

```
[  0.     1.25   2.5    3.75   5.     6.25   7.5    8.75  10.  ]
```

Comment: start + np.arange(num)*step

Comment: From a readability standpoint, this should be the way to go.

Comment: It's sadly not very readable at all when you're doing it with datetime64 values. Or at least to me it ends up looking very confusing. Probably ok if it lives in a function with a sensible name though

Answer (score 5):

```
def by_num_ele(start,step,n_elements):
    return numpy.arange(start,start+step*n_elements,step)
```

maybe?

Comment: Doesn't always work with floats: `by_num_ele(0, 0.1, 3)` gives `[0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` instead of the expected result `[0., 0.1, 0.2]`

Comment: you replace `n_elements` with `n_elements - 1`

Comment: @valentin - Nope, then all the other (normal) cases don't work. The 0.1 x 3 case is special because in python, 0.1*3 > 0.3 due to the way floats work and binary precision, etc, etc...

Answer (score 5):

Some of the other solutions didn't work for me, so since I was already comfortable using `np.linspace` I decided to throw together a function that replaces `linspace`'s `num` with a `step` argument.

```
def linspace(start, stop, step=1.):
  """
    Like np.linspace but uses step instead of num
    This is inclusive to stop, so if start=1, stop=3, step=0.5
    Output is: array([1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3.])
  """
  return np.linspace(start, stop, int((stop - start) / step + 1))
```

An example output:

```
linspace(9.5, 11.5, step=.5)
array([ 9.5, 10. , 10.5, 11. , 11.5])
```

Edit: I misread the question, the original question wanted a function that omitted the `stop` argument. I'll still leave this here, as I think it could be useful to some who stumble upon this question as it's the only one I've found that's similar to my original question of finding a function with `start`, `stop`, and `step`, rather than `num`

Comment: This solution is dangerous, in that a general user might assume that the resulting steps will always be as specified. However, consider the function with `linspace(9.5, 11.6, step=.5)` and the resulting array `[ 9.5   10.025 10.55  11.075 11.6  ]`. Of course, in that specific case, not all three inputs can be met, but it's not obvious from the function description that the resulting stepsize will be 0.525.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that should always work with floats.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import itertools
>>> def my_range(start, step, num):
...     return np.fromiter(itertools.count(start, step), np.float, num)
... 
>>> my_range(0, 0.1, 3)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2])
```

You could make the `np.float` an arg (or kwarg) if you want to use it with something other than floats:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import itertools
>>> def my_range(start, step, num, dtype=np.float):
...     return np.fromiter(itertools.count(start, step), dtype, num)
... 
>>> my_range(0, 5, 3)
array([  0.,   5.,  10.])
>>> my_range(0, 5, 3, dtype=np.int)
array([ 0,  5, 10])
```