# How to use modulo operator to print non-sequential number in Python

Tags: python, arrays, modulo

I am wondering, how could I use modulo operator to print only 6th, 16th, 26th, 36th elements of the array `A = np.arange(0, 1000)`

Thanks!

Comment: Use `A[6:46:10]`

Comment: The modulo operator seems like the wrong choice here.  Why do you want to use it?

Comment: If you really have to use modulo, it's `if i % 10 == 6:`

Comment: I may be wrong about it, but I thought it would be the most appropriate approach. What would be another way of doing this?

Comment: See the first comment.

Comment: @aminrd this answers my question! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a numpy function that allows you to specify start, step, and number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820107/is-there-a-numpy-function-that-allows-you-to-specify-start-step-and-number)