# How can I create a list of range of numbers as a column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
           'a': [20, 100],
           'b': [2, 3],
           'dir': ['long', 'short']
        }
 )
```

Expected output: Creating column `x`:

```
     a  b    dir    x
0   20  2   long    [22, 24, 26]
1  100  3  short    [97, 94, 91]
```

Steps:

`x` is a list with length of 3. `a` is starting point of `x` and `b` is step that `a` increases/decreases depending on `dir`. If `df.dir == long` `x` ascends otherwise it descends.

My Attempt based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45233237/10200497):

```
df['x'] = np.arange(0, 3) * df.b + df.a
```

Which does not produce the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, one thing I forgot to explain: Pandas isn't great with nested data, which makes me think this might be an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). In other words, there might be better solutions. It's perfectly clear what you're trying to do, but not why you're trying to do it.

Comment: @wjandrea I know that. This is just for final output for excel. I dont want to create multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a vectorial approach with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

```
# create 1 for long, else -1
d = np.where(df['dir'].eq('long'), 1, -1)[:,None]

# convert a and b to numpy as a column vector
a = df['a'].to_numpy()[:,None]
b = df['b'].to_numpy()[:,None]

# combine
N = 3
x = np.arange(1, N+1)
df['x'] = list(a + d*b*x)
```

Output:

```
     a  b    dir             x
0   20  2   long  [22, 24, 26]
1  100  3  short  [97, 94, 91]
```

Comment: Do you think my post is not suitable for SO? I just had a discussion in comments. I want to know your opinion. Is objective not clear? Is this style of asking question not suitable?

Comment: It probably could have had more details, but it was clear enough to me as it is.

Comment: In what way I need to add details? I can delete my comments after this. I know it is not suitable to talk about these here

Comment: @mozway, master of `np`. x_Amir_x, I don't mind switching the green mark to this answer ;)

Comment: @Timeless He is not a human. I am pretty sure :) I change the accepted answer :)

Comment: @x_Amir_x maybe adding a breakup of the computation `[20+N*1, 20+N*2, 20+N*3]`? But as I said, if was clear to **me** when I read the question.

Comment: @mozway I am planning to break the record of cups of coffees that you have ever received.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One possible option :

```
N = 3

sign = {"long": +1, "short": -1}

df["x"] = [
    np.arange(a+sb, a+sb*(N+1), step=sb)# .tolist() ?
    for a,sb in zip(df["a"], df["b"].mul(df["dir"].map(sign)))
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     a  b    dir             x
0   20  2   long  [22, 24, 26]
1  100  3  short  [97, 94, 91]

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Assuming only long/short you could use `step=1 if sb == 'long' else -1` instead of `map`

Comment: @mozway, I'll try that. BTW, do you have any suggestions to improve my logic/math/np skills ?

Comment: honestly I think you're already doing great. You mostly have high quality answers. Keep practicing as you do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
           'a': [20, 100],
           'b': [2, 3],
           'dir': ['long', 'short']
        }
 )

def generate_x(row):
    if row['dir'] == 'long':
        return [row['a'] + i * row['b'] for i in range(1, 4)]
    elif row['dir'] == 'short':
        return [row['a'] - i * row['b'] for i in range(1, 4)]

# Apply the custom function to each row and create a new column 'x'
df['x'] = df.apply(lambda row: generate_x(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

which prints:

```
     a  b    dir             x
0   20  2   long  [22, 24, 26]
1  100  3  short  [97, 94, 91]
```